# count occurrences in binary file Python 2X

Tags: python, python-2.7, count, binary

I want to count the occurrences of a particular header section in a binary file with Python 2.7.3. I have found plenty of examples to count occurrences in .txt type files and to do with lines but little info on counting byte sequences in binaries.

Thoughts are you would use the ASCII characters in the binary to use a string to search for.

The header section in hex is `"28 00 28 00 28 00"` or `"( ( ( "` in ascii.

I thought the code would be something like this:

```
total = 0
for line in f:
    if "( ( ( " in line:
        total += 1
f.close()
print "%s" % total
```

But it doesn't even seem to count  once, it'll print line and that is 120 chars long.

Answer (score 1):

You have *NULL* bytes, not spaces. By using `'( ( ( '` are looking for `28 20 28 20 28 20`, not `28 00 28 00 28 00`.

Use `\x00` to create such bytes:

```
if "(\x00(\x00(\x00" in line:
```

Looping over a binary file in *lines* may not make sense; this would only work if there were actually `\n` bytes in that file.

You could search through the file in chunks rather than lines:

```
previous = ''
total = 0
for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(2048), ''):
    if "(\x00(\x00(\x00" in previous + chunk:
        total += 1
    previous = chunk[-5:]  # ensure we don't miss matches at boundaries
```

Comment: Thanks for that, rookie mistake, with the updated IF statement the total count is still 0. Would bytes be better than to use than "lines" in the FOR statement?

Comment: @Python_newbie: so are you 100% certain those byte sequences are there? For binary files, I'd read in chunks (and take the last 5 bytes from the preceding chunk along for the next test, to ensure you didn't miss a partial match).

Comment: yes they sure are, I can find every header instance in the Hex Editor "Find selection" search criteria. There's at a guess 1000 x 3 different types of headers so that's why I am wanting a script to count and print a confirmed total. Reading in chunks won't work as the metadata can vary in length that's why searching for the header byte sequence is the best option afaik.

Comment: @Python_newbie: and the header doesn't contain any length information then?

Comment: yip it does, in total the header is 40 bytes long, byte blocks 32 - 35 and 36 - 39 contain the length of metadata as LONG and little endian. struct unpack can work to read that but at this stage the goal is to return a count of how many times that header occurs in the binary. I couldn't get it to work via your method as total still remained at 0 once I printed total

Comment: @Python_newbie: can you provide us with a sample of the file at all? `print repr(f.read(1024))` would already be helpful.

Comment: I got it to work in the end, basically I used the .count attribute and opened the file in 'rb' mode and then read the entire file in assigned "data" and then went "data.count("(\x00(\x00(\x00") and it returned 1363

Comment: @Python_newbie: are you saying you didn't open the file in binary mode in the first place?

Comment: yip I had been trying "rb" mode for binary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75049/discussion-between-python-newbie-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use ```total += (previous + chunk).count(needle)```? In case there's more than one "needle" inside chunk